# How can I create a dialog with each dialog item being a label and then a checkbox?

Tags: android

How can I create a dialog with each dialog item being a label and then a checkbox?

And when user click 'ok' to the dialog, I can tell in my code which on of the dialog item has been checked?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alertdialog.Builder setMultiChoiceItems(..)` is an option. [Link](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems%28java.lang.CharSequence[],%20boolean[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener%29).

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder` is likely what you want. `setSingleChoiceItems` will cover you if you only want the user to select one item.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html).
The Android API demos have an example of using it [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/RadioGroup1.html).

Not quite a checkbox, but a radio group allows you to click on the radio button from the list, and keep track of which one was selected. I have used one to do what you described (although I used an Activity instead of a Dialog, and used  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in my manifest to make my pretend dialog activity -look- like a Dialog).

The biggest problem though, is that RadioGroup only allows you to choose -one- item. So if you want to be able to select multiple items, then it will not work.